# Unable to run VBScript on Windows Kiosk computer using iexplore.exe as Shell

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, vbscript

I have a computer set up as a kiosk running `iexplore.exe` as the shell and the below VBScript is set to run at login for the kiosk user. The script is supposed to open Internet Explorer if it is closed. The script works fine with `explorer.exe` set as the shell, but not `iexplore.exe`. Can anyone tell me why?

```vb
ie=1
While ie=1
  Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  ie = WshShell.Run("iexplore.exe http://www.marion.k12.fl.us/", 3, true)
  Do Until ie = WshShell.Run("iexplore.exe http://www.marion.k12.fl.us/", 3, True)
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
  Loop
Wend
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing that WScript.Shell won't work with anything other than Explorer as the shell.  It will be difficult to find documentation stating one way or the other, though.  You might try using WMI to start IE instead: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_process_start.htm#Example_1_-_Launching_a_Processes_on_the_Local_Machine

Comment: Also, have your script log the error message that is being returned--that could be important info that readers need to provide help.

Answer (score 0):

First rule if .Run (or .Exec) fails (with or without a "File not found" error message): **Use full pathes!**. That is especially important, if the user is not the 'normal one' or the script is run 'early' (before the settings you rely on are actually active).

P.S. [.Run(,, True)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) waits for the process and returns its exit code. So I can't see any rhyme or reason in `Do Until ie = WshShell.Run()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you cannot run a script with IE set as the shell. To run a script it requires that explore.exe to be set as the shell.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/0966e5e5-2d16-4d5c-a720-409dacf0acc1/cant-run-vbscript-code-without-explorerexe-process-running?forum=ITCG